# Components are hidden only on page reload(vue js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, axios, laravel-mix

Good evening. With user authorization, two components should be hidden in the header without rebooting (via axios). But they only hide on reboot. With logout operation happens the same thing. What shall I do to take the necessary result?

header.vue

```
<template>
            <li v-if="!user.name" class="nav-item">
                <router-link to="/login"><b>Login</b></router-link>
            </li>
            <hr />
            <li v-if="!user.name" class="nav-item">
                <router-link to="/signup"><b>Registration</b></router-link>
            </li>
</template>

<script>
...
    computed: {
        token() {
            return this.token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    },
    mounted(){
    const self = this;
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}`
    axios.get('/api/user').then(function (response) {
        self.user = response.data

        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    },

    methods: {
        logout()
        {
            axios.post('/api/logout').then(() => {
                localStorage.removeItem('token')
                this.$router.push('/login')
            }).catch((errors) => {
                console.log(errors)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

login.vue

```
<template>
...
</template>

...
    methods: {
        loginUser(){
            const self = this;
            axios.post('/api/login', this.form).then((response) => {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data)
                console.log('logged');
                self.$router.push({ name: "CV"});
            }).catch((error)=>{
                self.validate = error.response.data.errors;
            })
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I guess that both components are rendered and after this, the `mounted` method is called. When you now call the `loginUser` or `logout` method, only the Local Storage state changes. This doesn't trigger a re-render because the Local Storage state isn't watched and therefor Vue doesn't "detect" that your token value has changed. I **recommend** to use a state management library like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) with a persistence extension instead of accessing the Local Storage by each component.